# Can gov't place a lien on assets or suspend drivers' licenses with Obamacare?

Tags: united-states, law, taxes, healthcare

Can anyone provide an objective source that if we refuse to pay penalties for Obamacare, the gov't can place liens on our assets or suspend our drivers' licenses?

Comment: @ChadJohnson still no idea what does it mean :v

Comment: What is the source of this claim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the IRS cannot impose any lien on your assets, prosecute you, garnish your wages, etc. if you don't comply with the Obamacare insurance mandate and fail to pay the penalty.  (And they certainly can't take away your driver's license, which is a state issue, not a federal issue.)

The Affordable Care Act [states](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/5000A):

> Notwithstanding any other provision of law—
>
> (A) Waiver of criminal penalties
>
> In the case of any failure by a taxpayer to timely pay any
> penalty imposed by this section, such taxpayer shall not be subject to
> any criminal prosecution or penalty with respect to such failure.
>
> (B) Limitations on liens and levies
>
> The Secretary shall not—
>
> (i) file
> notice of lien with respect to any property of a taxpayer by reason of
> any failure to pay the penalty imposed by this section, or
>
> (ii) levy on any such property with respect to such failure.

In fact, the only thing the IRS can do to collect the penalty is to deduct it out of your tax refund if you get one.  But if you're not getting a tax refund and you pay all your taxes except the Obamacare penalty, the IRS is powerless to make you pay it.

You may be wondering why the Obamacare mandate is so light on enforcement.  You see, the original House version of the bill gave the IRS the power to enforce payment of the penalty the way it would enforce payment of any other tax.  But then when the bill went to the Senate, an important provision in the House bill, the public option, was stripped out.  Liberals, who had been championing the passage of Obamacare, were [outraged](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIZB8Slw-zA).  (One of the key selling points of healthcare reform had been that the government would provide competition to private insurers.)  As a result, they grew less supportive of the mandate, because they saw it as fundamentally unfair that someone would have to buy insurance from a for-profit insurance company without having the option of buying it from the government instead.  So liberal distrust of the mandate led to the enforcement teeth being taken out.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm just describing the enforcement powers of the IRS.  Under the ACA, you still have a legal obligation to pay the penalty.  So if you want to be a law-abiding citizen, either pay the penalty or get health insurance.

Comment: I wonder if I should raise my W4 exemptions artificially now? I am single, but I pay a mortgage and property tax, so maybe I will use "4." I'm using "3" already (apparently I should only be using "2").

Comment: @ChadJohnson Well, if you reduce your withholdings too much, then you'll face the underpayment penalty.  And in any case the penalty is pretty small, so is it really worth adjusting your withholdings?

Comment: For me, the penalty of not having insurance would be $3,525 at 2.5%. I don't consider that to be small, so yes, I feel adjusting my withholdings is necessary.

Comment: @ChadJohnson Have you calculated whether you'll hit the underpayment penalty if you reduce your withholdings?  Oh, and 2.5% is for 2016.   For 2014 it's only 1%.

Comment: Ah, right, I meant to say in 2016. Yeah I'm trying to figure that out now about the underpayment penalty. Thanks again :)

Comment: Can the IRS say "You paid X amount instead of X+Y, so we're going to apply that to Y first.  Oh look, your X is short..."?

Comment: @Bobson - yes it can...

Comment: @Chad - So couldn't they then go after you for not paying all your taxes?  You paid the full Obamacare penalty (Y), but your taxes (X) are now short...  Which then re-fangs the law.

Comment: @Bobson No, the IRS can't do that.  How it would be collected is that on the income tax form (in 2015) you would check off the box that says you're paying the penalty.  So if you don't check it off then they can't apply the amount you paid to the penalty.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - So you are saying that you can cheat and not tell them you don't have insurance?  You think that is the better solution?

Comment: @Bobson - That is what the Supreme Court of the United States said in The National Federation of Independent Business (NFIB) v. Sebelius .  That was one of the challenges and they said that a taxpayer could **not** choose to not pay that tax if it is owed.

Comment: @Chad No, I'm not saying it's a better solution.  I'm not advising people to break the law and not pay the penalty.  I'm just saying that the IRS has little enforcement power concerning the penalty, other than deducting it out of your tax refund.

Comment: @Chad The court said that the penalty was constitutional under the taxing power.  So yes, you do have a legal obligation to pay the penalty.  I was just addressing he enforcement question.

Comment: We will find out in a few years when they actually start enforcing the provision.  I suspect that you will find that I am right.

Comment: @Chad "I suspect you will find that I am right."  It turned out I was right: "Indeed, the only way the IRS can collect the Obamacare penalty is by deducting it from the refund you'd otherwise be due. If you don't have a refund coming to you, then the penalty amount simply carries forward to future years, presumably accumulating interest but otherwise being practically unenforceable." http://www.dailyfinance.com/2015/06/25/can-you-really-ignore-obamacare-penalty/

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Until you file next year and they apply your withheld amount, and any payment first towards that penalty then towards your current year income tax.  Then start hitting you with leans and penalties on the unpaid income tax from that year.

Comment: @Chad No, the IRS doesn't have the ability to prioritize whether to apply your payment to unpaid tax bills from previous years.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - I will tell them you said that...

Answer (score 1):

Keshav was right:

https://www.healthinsurance.org/obamacare/the-obamacare-penalty-facts-and-fiction/

You can avoid the mandate indefinitely so long as you don't receive a refund...

Comment: Could you add some summary from this link?